# Sphinx Ubuntu 14 c++ sphinx_config.h not found

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have installed PocketSphinx on Ubuntu 14 and now trying to create simple sample. I took code from official website [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx).

```
#include <pocketsphinx.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ps_decoder_t *ps;
    cmd_ln_t *config;
    FILE *fh;
    char const *hyp, *uttid;
        int16 buf[512];
    int rv;
    int32 score;
config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
             "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
             "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.dmp",
             "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
             NULL);

if (config == NULL)
    return 1;
ps = ps_init(config);
if (ps == NULL)
    return 1;

fh = fopen("goforward.raw", "rb");
if (fh == NULL)
    return -1;
    rv = ps_start_utt(ps);
if (rv < 0)
    return 1;
    while (!feof(fh)) {
        size_t nsamp;
        nsamp = fread(buf, 2, 512, fh);
        rv = ps_process_raw(ps, buf, nsamp, FALSE, FALSE);
    }
    rv = ps_end_utt(ps);
if (rv < 0)
    return 1;
hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, &score);
if (hyp == NULL)
    return 1;
printf("Recognized: %s\n", hyp);

fclose(fh);
    ps_free(ps);
    cmd_ln_free_r(config);
return 0;
}
```

And Qmake is

```
    QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = OpenCVQt
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

DEPENDPATH += /usr/local/lib

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/pocketsphinx
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/sphinxbase

LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
LIBS +=-lpocketsphinx
LIBS += -lsphinxbase
LIBS += -lsphinxad

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Can't understand what is wrong. I saw sphinx_config.h in /usr/local/include/sphinxbase. Thanks.

```
  18:54:06: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/home/warezovvv/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug -o Makefile ../OpenCVQt/OpenCVQt.pro
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../OpenCVQt -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/pocketsphinx -I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase -I../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include -I../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../OpenCVQt/main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/sphinxbase/cmd_ln.h:66:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.h:52,
                 from ../OpenCVQt/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/sphinxbase/prim_type.h:88:27: fatal error: sphinx_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sphinx_config.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
18:54:06: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project OpenCVQt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
18:54:06: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

No error with header. Now new error ->

```
22:42:41: Running steps for project OpenCVQt...
22:42:41: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
22:42:41: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/home/warezovvv/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug -o Makefile ../OpenCVQt/OpenCVQt.pro
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../OpenCVQt -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/pocketsphinx -I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase -I/usr/include/sphinxbase -I../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include -I../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../OpenCVQt/main.cpp
../OpenCVQt/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
../OpenCVQt/main.cpp:14:22: error: 'MODELDIR' was not declared in this scope
              "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
                      ^
../OpenCVQt/main.cpp:15:30: error: expected ')' before string constant
              "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.dmp",
                              ^
../OpenCVQt/main.cpp:16:32: error: expected ')' before string constant
              "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
                                ^
../OpenCVQt/main.cpp:9:23: warning: unused variable 'uttid' [-Wunused-variable]
     char const *hyp, *uttid;
                       ^
../OpenCVQt/main.cpp: At global scope:
../OpenCVQt/main.cpp:4:1: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
 main(int argc, char *argv[])
 ^
../OpenCVQt/main.cpp:4:1: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
22:42:42: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project OpenCVQt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
22:42:42: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Comment: When you ask about compiler problems please provide the compiler output including compiler command line. You can find it in IDE window.

Comment: See See http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-quick-tour.html#viewing-output

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks for your answer! I have added output in question. Hope it help!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with this CMake config:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules(POCKETSPHINX REQUIRED pocketsphinx)
pkg_check_modules(SPHINXBASE REQUIRED sphinxbase)

message(STATUS "SPHINXBASE_LIBRARIES => " "${SPHINXBASE_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "POCKETSPHINX_LIBRARIES => " "${POCKETSPHINX_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "POCKETSPHINX_INCLUDE_DIRS => " "${POCKETSPHINX_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "SPHINXBASE_INCLUDE_DIRS => " "${SPHINXBASE_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

set(
  your_pocketsphinx_app_src
  your_pocketsphinx_app.cpp
  ...
)

add_executable(your_pocketsphinx_app your_pocketsphinx_app.cpp)
  set_property(TARGET your_pocketsphinx_app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)  
  target_include_directories(your_pocketsphinx_app PUBLIC ${POCKETSPHINX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_include_directories(your_pocketsphinx_app PUBLIC ${SPHINXBASE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_compile_options(your_pocketsphinx_app PUBLIC ${POCKETSPHINX_CFLAGS_OTHER})
  target_compile_options(your_pocketsphinx_app PUBLIC ${SPHINXBASE_CFLAGS_OTHER})
  target_link_libraries(your_pocketsphinx_app ${SPHINXBASE_LIBRARIES})
  target_link_libraries(your_pocketsphinx_app ${POCKETSPHINX_LIBRARIES})

# Binary to be installed.
install(TARGETS your_pocketsphinx_app DESTINATION bin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have installation of sphinxbase headers in `/usr/include`, not in `/usr/local/include`. If you intentionally compiled sphinxbase this way, you need to add `-I/usr/include/sphinxbase` in Makefile, not `-I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase`.

Overall pocketsphinx-5prealpha requires sphinxbase-5prealpha and default installation prefix for them is /usr/local. I suggest you to remove sphinxbase from /usr.

Comment: You have to define MODELDIR in Makefile. Something like CFLAGS += -DMODELDIR "/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model". Or just hardcode MODELDIR in sources.

Comment: Tutorial says about that: The MODELDIR macro is defined on the GCC command-line by using pkg-config to obtain the modeldir variable from PocketSphinx configuration. On Windows, you can simply add a preprocessor definition to the code, such as this:

#define MODELDIR "c:/sphinx/model"